# AngularJS function from service is being called twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post

I'm having trouble running a function from a service, because it is being called twice.

I've noticed that most of the problems of this nature are because people tend to call their controller twice (one time in the router and another in the view with ng-controller). But I checked, and my controller is not being invoked twice. Also: only on function from the service is being called twice.

Here it is:

```
.factory('findingsService', ['$http', '$log', '$q', '$cookies', function ($http, $log, $q, $cookies) {
return {

    // THIS FUNCTION IS WORKING FINE!

    list_findings: function(examId) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        var session_token = $cookies.get('ACCESS_TOKEN');
        $http.get(WS + URI_FINDINGS, {
                headers: {
                    'sessionToken': session_token,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                params: {
                    'examId': examId
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                defer.resolve(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function (data) {
                defer.reject(data);
            });

        return defer.promise;
    },

    // THIS FUNCTION IS BEING CALLED TWICE

    attach_findings_to_exam: function(examId, findingsObj) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        var session_token = $cookies.get('ACCESS_TOKEN');

        $http.post(WS + URI_FINDINGS, findingsObj, {
            headers: {
                'sessionToken': session_token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            params: {
                'examId': examId
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            defer.resolve(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (data) {
            defer.reject(data);
        });

        return defer.promise;
    }
  }
}])
```

Since it's the same service and only one function is being called twice, and think that discarding the controller issue is fine. Can it be something about the global configuration of the $http.post?

Comment: is there a specific controller using this service?

Comment: not going to fix issue but using a new `$q.defer()` is an anti-pattern when `$http` already returns a promise. Create a demo that reproduces this

Comment: you need to show us where you are injecting this service, your problem is not in the definition of the function.